# iPhone Full Screen Image

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari

How do I go about making an image or section of the page full screen on the iPhone?

I have an image that is 480 x 320 and I want to pull that up full screen on the iPhone but it has to be within a webpage so that I can make the image a link back to the previous page.

Currently if I drop the image on a blank page and I open it up on the iPhone it just shows up in the top left corner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say set the viewport meta tag in your blank page so Safari knows to render the page at the right size.  For more information, see this link:

[Apple iPhone Safari Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/chapter_4_section_5.html)

Answer (score 18):

Hopefully I'm not in breach of the NDA here, but here goes.

Mobile Safari, by default, renders a page as if that page had been viewed by a desktop browser, with a default width of 980 pixels.

To change this behavior you need to explicitly declare the viewport, which you do via meta tags. If you declare the width to the constant *device-width*, it'll default to 320 instead of 980, and everything looks great.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />
</head>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but some examples I've seen also include the minimum-scale and maximum-scale as well. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 2):

nice links which may help you further:

How to optimize your website for mobile devices:
http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2008/12/01/optimizing-a-website-for-iphone/