# Any way to make small web pages show up full size on iPhone?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iphone, html

I'm currently working on an intracompany web site which will be viewed on cell phones - at the moment, Palm Treos and iPhones.  The Treo has a screen 360x360 so I'm putting all the page info into a 360x360 box.  Works fine on the Treo, but when you log in to the site on an iphone, it shows up about 1/2in square on the screen.  Is there any way I can, from the server side, make it show up full screen on an iPhone?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121051/iphone-full-screen-image

Comment: Thanks - I didn't think of checking for dups - shame on me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `<head>` section of your HTML document, add:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
```

That should make it appear the correct size on the iPhone!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you might want to make a different CSS version for iPhone browsers. [Here's a neat little page](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/07/web-development-for-the-iphone/) on targeting the iPhone browser through HTML and PHP. There's also quite a bit more information on developing websites for the iPhone on that page.

Hope that helps!